# "Se" + verb in a Canadian French spoken manner?

Tags: verbes, canada

My girlfriend keeps teasing me about a structure of my spoken French. I often say: "On va se regarder un film", meaning that me and my girlfriend are going to watch a movie. I have the impression that it is correct spoken French, but she is sure of the contrary. I might get this from my family though. However, I also heard: "On va se joindre à eux", "On pourrait se bâtir une maison" or "On pourrait aller se manger un cornet de crème glacée". Am I correct to use French to speak with "se" + verb?

Comment: C'est tout à fait correct à l'oral. (Je suis Français.)

Comment: @AmandeAdorable Both

Comment: Alors pourquoi poser la question en anglais...

Comment: Parce que je pensais que c'était un site en anglais. Je voulais juste que tout le monde comprenne bien. Je peux parler francais avec grand plaisir

Comment: N'hésite pas à donner ton avis des phrases sous la réponse de jlliagre...

Answer (score 4):

This reflexive form seems to be less used in Canadian French, the reason why it might be perceived as incorrect.

It is very common and standard in the French spoken in Southern France (like it is in Catalan, Spanish and Italian), and is slowly spreading to the rest of France where it might still be considered colloquial, depending on the verb used.

Don't confuse it with forms where the pronoun is mandatory, ***on va se joindre à eux*** is always used because ***on <s>va joindre à</s> eux*** doesn't work or where the pronoun is optional but plays a role like in ***se bâtir une maison***. Dropping it would mean build a house for someone else.

On the other hand, ***se manger un** cornet* is a good example because you can't eat something for someone else.

Here are some other ones:

> **Je vais me boire une bière**.

> [**Je m'essaye la** lucky ce we ...](http://www.achigan.net/msgforum.php?id_sujet=17487)

> [**Tu te la prends** la BD ?](http://le-regard-de-papa-et-maman.blogspot.com/2020/11/ma-wishlist-pour-noel-2020.html)

Comment: @AmandeAdorable Je me suis peut-être trompé mais *se faire une petite bouffe* est standard car le pronom n'est pas "superflu". Est-ce qu'on dit chez toi  *Je vais me manger une poutine ?*

Comment: @AmandeAdorable *On se fait une petite bouffe* ≠ *On fait une petite bouffe*.

Comment: @AmandeAdorable *Je vais manger une bouillabaisse* = *Je vais me manger une bouillabaisse*.

Comment: *On se fait une petite bouffe* : on est entre nous, *On fait une petite bouffe* : on organise une petite bouffe.

Comment: @AmandeAdorable Tu ne m'as pas répondu pour l'acceptabilité de *je vais me manger une poutine*.

Comment: Je sais pas trop, ça se dit mal ou les deux sons seraient mélangés. Je suis pas certain, c'est certainement plus explétif... Je sais pas si je vois ça différemment selon si c'est 1-2 ou 3e personne. Peut-être plus avec _prendre_ et _chercher_.

Comment: @AmandeAdorable *Il va se manger une poutine* ?

Comment: _On va se manger une poutine ?_ oui, bien je pense. Je suis pas toujours très représentatif. @Robert Tu penses quoi de ces phrases-là toi ?

Comment: @AmandeAdorable Tu as changé le pronom parce que "***Il** va se manger*..." passe moins bien ?

Comment: Ça donne quasiment un trompe-l'oeil i.e. _au visage_ ? Mais oui, essentiellement ça passe moins bien, pour ça ou autrement. J'ai de la difficulté à départager. Mais _se regarder un film_ passe bien, familier. Quand c'est superflu dans certains cas je le perçois comme _très_ familier. Donc c'était un cas d'hypercorrection entre deux francophones. Elle réagissait au registre. Je pense qu'on est tous interpellés à cause de trucs régionaux différents, tel un nexus.

Comment: @AmandeAdorable https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/se-boire-une-bi%C3%A8re-se-manger-une-pizza.705941/post-3882915

Comment: Avec _boire_, je trouve ça bien plus usuel qu'avec _manger_. Que ce soit _aller se boire une bière_, ou demander _si on se la boit cette bière-là_ etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122390/discussion-between-amande-adorable-and-jlliagre).

Answer (score 1):

Je fais mien l'avertissement contenu dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44968/26366) sur la confusion possible avec des verbes [pronominaux](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2939) à différents degrés. Ceci dit on peut avoir un emploi similaire au « datif éthique » (LBU14  § 672 e) ou [*pronom d'intérêt, explétif*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=2927), normalement avec la première ou deuxième personne :

> [*Se*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/se), en fonction de « datif éthique », exprime l'intérêt que
> prend à l'action la personne qui parle ou indique qu'on sollicite
> l'interlocuteur ou le lecteur de s'intéresser à l'action] *On se boit
> un p'tit verre ?* (TLFi, « [se](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/se) » )

Contrairement aux autres exemples de la question « On va se joindre à eux » demande obligatoirement le pronom etc. On peut noter qu'on trouve des nuances dans des emplois de verbes pronominaux de sens [indistinct](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?th=2&id=2956) ou subjectifs, incluant des particularités régionales pour tel ou tel verbe. On dit que « c'est surtout chez les Méridionaux que l'on trouve des pronoms superflus » (LBU14  § 779 c). Au Canada. on a par exemple *se mériter*, *se lutter*, *se pratiquer*, *s'ambitionner*.

---

Avec « on va se regarder un film » on a une formulation où le pronom (*se*) n'est pas requis (contrairement à l'exemple avec *se joindre*), qui pourrait manifester davantage l'intérêt de la personne qui s'exprime, probablement de manière familière, ou régionale.